# Scheduled task & PowerShell Script not being executed

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I know this has been asked a 1000 times and I think I looked through all of them.

I have scheduled tasks running PowerShell Scripts on other servers already, but not on this server. Which has me scratching my head as to why I can't get it to work on this server.

I have a powershell script on a Windows 2008 R2 server. I can run it manually and it all works perfectly, but when I try to run it from a scheduled task the History says it was run, but the PowerShell script does not execute.

PSRemoting is enabled

The server ExecutionPolicy is "RemoteSigned"

I get two entries in the History

1. Action completed
   Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Processing" , instance "{dbbd4924-42d6-4024-a8ed-77494c7f84cf}" , action "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.EXE" with return code 0.
2. Task complted
   Task Scheduler successfully finished "{dbbd4924-42d6-4024-a8ed-77494c7f84cf}" instance of the "\Processing" task for user "domain\user".

The Scheduled Task looks like this:

1. I set to run under my account while I'm logged on. (since I can run the script manually as myself already)
2. checked Run with highest privileges.
3. trigger is to run every 10 minutes
4. Start a program Action.... Powershell.exe
5. Arguments: -executionpolicy remotesigned -File D:\abc\def\powershell\Processing.ps1
6. Conditions & Settings default settings.

Comment: So what is failing? Task Scheduler is reporting success, which just means that `powershell.exe` ran successfully.I'm guessing this means you're not getting the desired results from your script. If that's the case, post the contents of the script.

Comment: If I run the powershell script outside of the scheduled task it runs correctly with the desired results.

Comment: Yes, but *we* don't know what the results you want are, and we can't tell what the script does. The task parameters alone aren't enough given the behavior. Some of the things you can execute will behave differently when run as a task. Without knowing what you're doing, we can't help. Post the code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post my code. There would have to be to much changed to post it on here.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you're not being blocked by a permission issue with the task:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist.aspx

The above GPO prevents credentials from being saved. Other User Rights Assignment settings can prevent things being run as batch/script/task/etc.

As a workaround, you can also set the task to run a .bat file with the powershell task. Adding an echo or pipe parameter may give you some clues to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you should add some diagnostic logging to this script to find out a place that causes this issue or redirect output of this script to a file. E.g. change your string with arguments this way:

`-executionpolicy remotesigned -File D:\abc\def\powershell\Processing.ps1 2>&1 d:\output.log`

Looks like that the script is executed, but something goes wrong. There are too many reasons for such behavior and it is difficult to find the root cause without a code.